# Archivo no encontrado java en Eclipse

Tags: java, archivo, eclipse

Sé que esta es una pregunta común, pero mi caso es muy particular.

No logro que mi programa encuentre el fichero de texto que tiene que leer. He intentado de todo, leerlo usando la función Scanner, leerlo usando las funciones FileReader y BufferedReader, escribiendo la dirección con `/` y con `\\`.

La única vez que leyó el archivo fue cuando lo escribí de la siguiente forma: `C:\\Users\\Jose\\Desktop\\Eclipse\\Traslate\\src\\com\\languages\\Idiomas.txt`.
Pero obviamente cuando mi profesor lo abrió en su computadora no hubo modo de que el programa encontrase el archivo. Incluso cuando él reemplazó la dirección completa por la de su computadora no funcionó.
Este es mi código inicial.

```
public void Lang () {
        
        File fLang = new File ("C:\\Users\\Jose\\Desktop\\Eclipse\\Traslate\\src\\com\\languages\\LANGS.txt");
        Scanner SFile;
        
        try {
            SFile = new Scanner(fLang);
            
            while (SFile.hasNextLine()) {
                
            String Words = SFile.nextLine();
            
            String [] Idi = Words.split("\\|");
            
             Spanish = Idi [0];
             English = Idi [1];
             French = Idi [2];
             German = Idi [3];
             
            /**
             * Instancia del Package Languages
             */
         Languages l = new Languages(Spanish,English,French,German);
         
         lang.add(l);
                
            }
            
            SFile.close();

        }
        
        
        
        catch (FileNotFoundException err) {
            
            System.out.print("El archivo no ha podido ser localizado\n");
            err.getStackTrace();
        }
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Cuál es exactamente la pregunta? Si ya viste que la ruta funcionó como nos indicas, qué necesitas resolver exactamente?

Comment: En lugar de usar rutas absolutas, intenta automatizar un poco las rutas con el método `getResource()`, así, si incluyes el archivo en tu proyecto y se lo pasas a alguien no habrá problemas. Al escribir la ruta completa desde la raíz `C:`, todos los directorios en todos los PC que abras el programa tendrán que llamarse igual, lo cual es complicado a la hora de querer probar el código en diferentes equipos. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3861989/5587982) donde se explican distintas formas de obtener la ruta de los archivos que son parte del proyecto sin rutas absolutas.

Comment: Pues, que cuando migro el programa a otra computadora (incluyendo la carpeta con los archivos de texto) el programa no encuentra el archivo. Básicamente el programa solo funciona en mi computadora y ese no es le deber ser.

Comment: A.Cedano Gracias mil.

Answer (score 0):

Eso se debe por varias razones.

Si funciona en tu equipo en los demás no debes poner la ruta relativa.

Debes de tener en cuenta el sistema operativo de cada usuario no se almacena igual en windows que en ubuntu y otras distribuciones el windows  seria C:\users\usuario\desktop\archivo.txt pero en ubuntu la barra es al revés /home/usuario/desktop/archivo.txt. Puedes subir el archivo en Internet  en un hosting como puede ser 000webhost enlace: https://es.000webhost.com/ y desde allí subir tu archivo y poner el enlace